# About the fundamental theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've came across the following equation in some proof:

> $y(t) = \int_{-\pi}^t(t-s)y(s) ds + \int_t^{\pi}(s-t)y(s)ds$, where $s,t\in [-\pi, \pi]$ and $y$ is integrable on $[-\pi, \pi]$.

Then, they want to take the derivative of the equation above, and simply says that the result is:

> $y'(t) = \int_{-\pi}^ty(s) ds - \int_t^{\pi}y(s) ds$

I can't understand - why is this the result? I know that the fundamental theorem of Calculus was used here (which states that if $F(x) = \int_a^xf(x)dx$ then $F'(x_0)=f(x_0) \forall x_0$ ), and I'm not sure how is it used in this case, where $t$ is the lower value in some of the integrals?

**EDIT**  following the comments, I tried calculating it, knowing that $\int_a^b = -\int^a_b$:

$\int_{-\pi}^t(t-s)y(s) ds + \int_t^{\pi}(s-t)y(s)ds = t\int_{-\pi}^ty(s) ds - \int_{-\pi}^tsy(s) ds - t\int_{\pi}^ty(s) ds  + \int_{\pi}^tsy(s) ds $.

So if I want to take the derivative of this equation, using the fundamental theorem (for general $t$), I'll get : $ty(t) - ty(t) -ty(t) + ty(t) = 0$. Where is my mistake? what did I miss?

Comment: If it makes it clearer, recall that $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=-\int_b^af(x)\,dx$

Comment: @lulu But it would only change $\int_t^{\pi}$ to $\int_{pi}^t$, wouldn't it? (And what is the meaning of it, knowing that $-\pi \le t \le \pi$ ?)

Comment: This can be seen as a special case of the Leibniz integral rule (which is a slight geenralisation of FTC): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Alternative_Proof_of_General_Form_with_Variable_Limits,_using_the_Chain_Rule

Comment: Yes, it would change to $-\int_{\pi}^t$, and that explains the negative when you differentiate. (You can also think about it geometrically: If $f>0$, for example, the function $\int_t^b f(u)\,du$ *decreases* as $t$ increases.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried it, and yet I could not get to the correct result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is also a function of $t$ inside the integral, you have two pieces to the differentiation. As @peek-a-boo commented, the result follows from the Leibniz rule, but we can do it directly with the product rule here.

If $f(t) = \int_a^t (t-s)y(s)\,ds$, then note that $$f(t) = t\int_a^t y(s)\,ds - \int_a^t sy(s)\,ds.$$ Using the fundamental theorem of calculus twice and the product rule on the first term, we get
$$f'(t) = \int_a^t y(s)\,ds + ty(t) - ty(t) = \int_a^t y(s)\,ds.$$
The other term is similar, reversing the limits on the definite integral as I already pointed out.